# What bone constraints should I use?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm trying to setup rigging a scales. I have 2 main bone (pan and indicator). I want indicator to rotate when pan move up - down and  I even want indicator rotation makes pan move up - down when I rotate indicator by an IK. I don't know what bone constraints should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you need is the [Transformation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/transformation.html) constraint. It allows you to map values from one transformation type (location, rotation or scale) of a bone to a transformation type of the target bone. This mapping can also switch X/Y/Z channels around and set appropriate limits and ranges.

If your case you would want to map the vertical location of the pan bone (in local space probably) to the rotation of your indication bone around the appropriate axis (probably also in local space).

Comment: Exactly Transformation constraint thank you!